# Battery issues: Laptop shuts down at 70% battery left

Tags: 16.04, dell, power-management, shutdown, battery

I am using *Dell latitude e6410* which is running 16.04 
The problem I am facing is that my laptop shuts down when the battery is at 65-70%. Sometimes it lasts till 10% but mostly it will shutdown when the battery is below 70%. I am not facing this issue on windows 7 though. And the battery backup is worst. I use it for 15-20 mins and it goes down to like 80%(does not happen in windows).

I used TLP but it did not help. What is the problem? How do I solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem, except it's at 60%. Battery goes down to 60%, says it has hours left, then shuts down!