# Laptop shuts down at half full battery

Tags: power-management, shutdown, laptop, battery

My laptop suddenly shuts down at approximately 50% of the battery left. If I try to turn it on, it shuts down typically before Ubuntu is loaded.

However, if I plug it in for a few minutes and then unplug, it continues to work until the battery is empty. [Here is a plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjOYE.png) of the battery charge, where you can see a feature at 50%, when the laptop shut down and I plugged it in for a minute.

What can be the cause of the problem?

I found a few probably related questions:

[Battery issues: Laptop shuts down at 70% battery left](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943342/battery-issues-laptop-shuts-down-at-70-battery-left)

[Ubuntu shuts down at 55% battery level](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695530/ubuntu-shuts-down-at-55-battery-level)

[Laptop shuts down at 40%-50% only on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984457/laptop-shuts-down-at-40-50-only-on-ubuntu)

but there is no good answer for them.

I'm using  MSI GF75 with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: *Generally* when this happens it is because the battery is beginning to fail. If it's unable to deliver the minimum voltage required for the machine to run, it will simply give up. Charging for a few minutes may excite the anodes enough to allow for better power delivery until the charge is actually depleted. Older batteries are also quite sensitive to cold. How old is the battery? How do you use it? What are the lifetime stats for it? 

Comment: Actually, I observe this behavior from the day of buy. Of cause, it is always possible that the battery is damaged, but in two of the questions, which I refer to, everything works nicely in Windows. Unfortunately, I can't check this. Still I suspect that this is some Ubuntu-related problem.

Comment: I am also facing same issue , for me it happens when i use vs code and if battery is unplugged and reached around 60 then its get shutdown , please let me know any solution if you resolve

Comment: @YashwanthSai I have checked this in windows, and the laptop didn't shut down indeed. As a partial solution for Ubuntu, I found that if I limit the CPU frequency to its minimum, the laptop works unplugged smoothly until the battery is empty.